# Showing S3DB Database in PHP

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, html-table

I currently have this table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-edited">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th name="brand">Brand</th>
    <th name="product">Product</th>
    <th name="availability">Availability</th>
    <th name="quantity">Quantity</th>
    <th name="price">Price</th>
    <th name="description">Description</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

I need help in viewing the database table for each column in the PHP table. I am only using Xampp and each PHP file and s3db database is in there. Can someone please guide me through the PHP code that I need to make it work.

So far i tried this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-edited">
  <?php

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:Products.s3db');

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Brand &nbsp </th>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Product &nbsp </th>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Availability &nbsp </th>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Quantity &nbsp </th>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Price &nbsp </th>";
    echo "<th> &nbsp Description &nbsp </th>";

    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($records as $r) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

?>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a tutorial site. We can help you fix problems in your code but won't walk you through writing that code in the first place.

Comment: So far i tried this but only the table fields are showing.. i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will helps you

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> &nbsp; Sl.No &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Brand &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Product &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Availability &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Quantity &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Price &nbsp; </th>
<th> &nbsp; Description &nbsp; </th>    
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:Products.s3db');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` ";

  $result = $db->query($sql);
      if($result){
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$i++.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['product'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['availability'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['price'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
                  </tr>';
        }

    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```